# Why doesn't IO.puts work for spawns inside an Enum.each?

Tags: elixir

```
Enum.each(1..100, fn(i)-> 
  spawn(fn-> IO.puts(i) end)
end)

spawn(fn-> IO.puts("HELLO") end)
```

I expect the first part to output 1 - 100 to the screen, but it does nothing. If I don't use `spawn`, and just say `IO.puts(i)` on the second line, it works fine -- so IO.puts works fine inside an `each` call. And the HELLO part works fine, so IO.puts works fine within a spawn. But the combination yields nothing.

Why is this?

Comment: I tried out your code in iex and it works for both examples.

Comment: I can confirm what @Gjaldon said.

Comment: I ran `.exs` from Sublime text using Ctrl-B option, it behaves like OP said.  Also, if I use `elixir test.exs`, then, too problem reported by OP happens

Answer (score 4):

***NOTE:*** This problem can be reproduced if you save the code in a `.exs` file and run at command line using `elixit <file-name>.exs`

---

> [spawn/1](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/processes.html#spawn) takes a function which it will execute in another process.

The spawned process will execute the given function and exit after the function is done

In your case, the parent process that runs the code terminates before the spawned processes could complete their execution.

If we add sleep, then, we will see the output:

```
Enum.each(1..100, fn(i)-> 
  spawn(fn-> IO.puts(i) end)
end)
spawn(fn-> IO.puts("HELLO") end)

:timer.sleep(1000)
```

You will not see this issue in `iex` as, in that case, the parent process that is running `spawn`ed processes is `iex` itself and it remains alive until you quit from it.